# ssh in to multiple VMs simultaneously

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine

I have to ssh into two VMs. The first VM is configured to be sshed into via port 22 by default. But what changes do I make and where to ssh into second VM from host terminal. even when I close the first VM login, I cannot ssh into VM_2 via port-22.

I'm using the command

```
ssh vm_2@ip_address -p port_number
```

#### EDIT:

Error msg:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.xxxxxxxxxxx port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: So you're trying to connect from VM1 to VM2?

Comment: What host are you trying to connect to vm2 from? What happens when you try? Do you get error messages? What do they say?

Comment: @Kenster i'm trying to connect vm_2 form host terminal. and edited the question. pls see error msg.

Comment: @Panki No i've to connect vm_2 from host

Comment: I've created these vms from virt-manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sshd` on your VM on a different port. If port 22 is bound to your host machine on the same port, then you must bind port 22 in your other VM to some other port on your host machine. Assuming you are using a sane VM client like VirtualBox, [you should be able to do this](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/).